# Can I manually connect my Facebook contacts to my AddressBook contacts?

Tags: photos.app, contacts, facebook

I have the following:

- Facebook friends
- iPhoto faces
- Address Book contacts

Faces and contacts are already linked. Some friends are also linked to the contacts. There is a problem with the friends that don't use their full name in their Facebook profile. They just don't.

**Is there a way to link them manually, so when I tag someone in iPhoto with his/her full name it will appear in Facebook (given the photo is shared from iPhoto) as tagged with the correct friend?**

PS: I have the iPhone Facebook app, if that helps (I think it has some kind of sync function).

Comment: As a hint for the "friends that don't use their full name in their Facebook profile" -- sometimes the syncing works if you add an e-mail-address to their contact that they've provided in their Facebook profile.

Comment: @doncherry: I know but what if I don't know their email address and it's not visible on their profile

Comment: Then it obviously won't work. I don't know of a way to get 100%.

Comment: I wonder if nicknames would do the trick...

Answer (score 3):

Your question is really confusing but let me try to answer it the best I can.

Let me start by mentioning that this is why I hate Facebook contact syncing. People (like myself) don't use their real info and when you sync data you end up with a mess in your address book. I personally would suggest that you don't do it that way. My contacts that I set up manually are waaaay more accurate than merging info from Facebook into my address book. It takes more work, but it's worth it.

To tag someone in Facebook you have to connect it to their Facebook account and use their Facebook name. You can tag photos with your own name but it won't link up to the person's FB account.

Also are you using the newest version of iPhoto? And are these photos that you are tagging being uploaded and shared from the iPhoto app itself? You can tag people in iPhoto and then upload the photo album from iPhoto and it will bring over all of the data for the people you tagged to FB. But like I said, you have to tag them using their FB name and not their real name for it to be able to link to their FB account.

As far as I know, there is no way to accomplish what you are trying to do at this point in time.

Comment: I am using the latest iPhoto ('11 I think) and I was afraid it would come up as a negative...

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that you can add the Facebook profile manually.  See details on this web page.  http://www.macworld.com/article/1161225/lion_address_book.html.  Basically, when editing the card, select Card.Add Field.Profile to add Profile to your card.  Change this to Facebook and then use the Facebook unique identifier (found at the end of the profile URL on Facebook).  However, it does not seem to be updating my image yet.